# Настройка ajax-части в отправке формы

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть код:

```
                        <form class="c-form" id="connectForm">
                            <div class="c-form__lineWrap">
                                <div class="c-form__line c-form__line--first">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <input type="text" class="c-form__input c-form__input--first c-form__input--required"
                                   name="name"
                                   placeholder="Имя и фамилия" required>
                            <input type="text" class="c-form__input c-form__input--required" name="phone"
                                   placeholder="Телефон" required>
                            <input type="email" class="c-form__input c-form__input--required" name="email"
                                   placeholder="E-mail" required>
                            <input type="text" class="c-form__input c-form__input--required" name="position"
                                   placeholder="Желаемая позиция" required>

                            <textarea rows="4" class="c-form__input"
                                      placeholder="Комментарий (необязательно)"></textarea>
                            <input type="submit" class="c-form__input c-form__button " id="c-form__submit">
                        </form>
```

Как настроить ajax-отпраку данной формы ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С помощью [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). Например так:

```js
$("#connectForm").submit(function(e) {
  var script = "/mail.php"; // скрипт обработки данных
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: script,
    data: $("#connectForm").serialize(), // все данные с формы
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data); // ответ от скрипта отправки
    },
    error: function() {
      console.log('Ошибка отправки');
    }
  });
  e.preventDefault(); // отменяем стандартную отправку
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="c-form" id="connectForm">
  <div class="c-form__lineWrap">
    <div class="c-form__line c-form__line--first">
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="text" class="c-form__input c-form__input--first c-form__input--required" name="name" placeholder="Имя и фамилия" required>
  <input type="text" class="c-form__input c-form__input--required" name="phone" placeholder="Телефон" required>
  <input type="email" class="c-form__input c-form__input--required" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" required>
  <input type="text" class="c-form__input c-form__input--required" name="position" placeholder="Желаемая позиция" required>

  <textarea rows="4" class="c-form__input" placeholder="Комментарий (необязательно)"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" class="c-form__input c-form__button " id="c-form__submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

На вскидку. Необходимо js , jquery собрать данные с формы , потом создать объект data в котором в парах ключ значение узказаны данные. после этого делаеться отправка одним из методов POST или GET (я обычно использую пост) на url который вам нужен , это можеть быть файл php или адрес сервера который примет данный запрос.

```
$('#c-form__submit').on('click',function(){
var name = $('input[name=name]').val();
var phone = $('input[name=phone]').val();
var email = $('input[name=email]').val();
var position = $('input[name=position]').val();
var data = {
    name : name,
    phone : phone,
    email : email,
    position : position
 };
 $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    data: data,
    success: success,
    dataType: dataType
});
```

});